# Is Yonezawa Sachiko inspired by Misawa Sachika?

Tags: joukamachi-no-dandelion, sachika-misawa

In *Joukamachi no Dandelion*, there is a character named Yonezawa Sachiko (aka "Sacchan"). There also exists a real human being named Misawa Sachika. Observe the following:

- Sachiko is voiced by Sachika.
- Their names are curiously similar, sharing three of five characters - 米**澤紗千**子 vs. 三**澤紗千**香.
- Sachiko is an idol. While I don't know that I would characterize Misawa as an "idol", per se, she is a skilled vocalist, and certainly strikes me as the idol "type" of voice actress.
- Sachiko has something of a resemblance to Sachika (though, granted, this is not a hugely uncommon look for a young Japanese woman to have):

  [image]　[image]

This leads me to wonder: was Sachiko inspired in some way by Sachika? Chronologically, it's feasible - *Joukamachi* has only been in print since June 2012, by which point, Sachika had already debuted (in 2008) and had her first major voice-acting role (Kuroyukihime in *Accel World*, in spring 2012).

Has the author of the manga (or, for that matter, Sachika herself) commented on this?

(Wikipedia claims that this is indeed the case; however, I would like to see some kind of citation if possible. Twitter, a manga afterword, whatever.)

Comment: Regarding the Idol part: "Sachika Misawa is the winner of the 2008 Kadokawa Up-Front Style Idol Seiyuu Audition."